# how to undo git merge unstaged changes when I already have other unstaged changes in my working directory?

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge

I cloned the single branch in a folder using  `git clone -b <branch-name> --single-branch <project-url>` then when i tried to checkout the master using git checkout master, i got the error "master not found".

Then I executed `git pull origin master` command and it automatically started merging my branch with master. after doing `git status` I found multiple changes which are ready to commit in branch along with my own changes in working directory.

Please suggest me how to just ignore the changes occurred due to merging and keep my unstaged changed in working directory.